# React useState with Object with multiple boolean fields

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

I have this object initialised with useState:

```
const [
    emailNotifications,
    setEmailNotifications,
  ] = useState<emailNotifications>({
    rating: false,
    favourites: false,
    payments: false,
    refunds: false,
    sales: false,
  });
```

And I created a function that should dynamically change the value for each field but I am struggling with assigning the opposite boolean value onClick. This is the function:

```
const handleEmailNotificationsSettings = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    setEmailNotifications({
      ...emailNotifications,
      [event.target.id]: !event.target.id,
    });
  };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is right just one minor thing that you trying to achieve here is wrong.

```
setEmailNotifications({
  ...emailNotifications,
  [event.target.id]: !event.target.id, //Here
});
```

when you are setting dynamic value to the state you are expecting it to be the Boolean value which is not

solution:

```
setEmailNotifications({
  ...emailNotifications,
  [event.target.id]: !emailNotifications[event.target.id],
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did try your solution but typescript is complaining:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'emailNotifications'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'emailNotifications'.

Comment: @EdoardoTrotta that sort of error is very common when dealing with forms since `e.target.value` etc is always just `string` even when you know it's more specific.  So you often have to use an `as` assertion.  In this case I think the best type-safe approach is a curried function.  I will write an answer.

Comment: @EdoardoTrotta to fix this answer you need to assert the type of the `id` like this: `!emailNotifications[event.target.id as keyof EmailNotifications]`

Comment: Thank you @Linda, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

@kunal panchal's answer is totally valid Javascript, but it does cause a Typescript error because the type of `event.target.id` is `string` so Typescript does not know for sure that it's a valid key of `emailNotifications`.  You have to assert that it is correct by using `as`.

```
!emailNotifications[event.target.id as keyof EmailNotifications]
```

---

One way to avoid this is to get the `boolean` value by looking at the `checked` property on the `input` rather than toggling the state.

As a sidenote, it's a good best practice to get the current state by using a `setState` callback so that you always get the correct value if multiple updates are batched together.

```
const _handleEmailNotificationsSettings = (
  event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => {
  setEmailNotifications(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [event.target.id]: event.target.checked,
  }));
};
```

This is probably the best solution for a checkbox.

---

Another approach which is more flexible to other situations is to use a curried function. Instead of getting the property from the `event.target.id`, where it will always be `string`, we pass the `property` as an argument to create an individual handler for each property.

```
const handleEmailNotificationsSettings = (
  property: keyof EmailNotifications
) => () => {
  setEmailNotifications((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [property]: !emailNotifications[property]
  }));
};
```

or

```
const handleEmailNotificationsSettings = (
  property: keyof EmailNotifications
) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setEmailNotifications((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [property]: event.target.checked
  }));
};
```

which you use like this:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  checked={emailNotifications.favourites}
  onChange={handleEmailNotificationsSettings("favourites")}
/>
```

---

Those solutions avoid having to make `as` assertions in the event handler, but sometimes they are inevitable.  I am looping through your state using `(Object.keys(emailNotifications)` and I need to make an assertion there because `Object.keys` always returns `string[]`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

// I am defining this separately so that I can use typeof to extract the type
// you don't need to do this if you have the type defined elsewhere
const initialNotifications = {
  rating: false,
  favourites: false,
  payments: false,
  refunds: false,
  sales: false
};

type EmailNotifications = typeof initialNotifications;

const MyComponent = () => {
  // you don't really need to declare the type when you have an initial value
  const [emailNotifications, setEmailNotifications] = useState(
    initialNotifications
  );

  const handleEmailNotificationsSettings = (
    property: keyof EmailNotifications
  ) => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setEmailNotifications((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [property]: event.target.checked
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {(Object.keys(emailNotifications) as Array<keyof EmailNotifications>).map(
        (property) => (
          <div key={property}>
            <label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id={property}
                checked={emailNotifications[property]}
                onChange={handleEmailNotificationsSettings(property)}
              />
              {property}
            </label>
          </div>
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```